# Which Tamil Scripture mentions about the doctrines of "Pancha Pakshi"?

Tags: astrology, tamil

My knowledge of "Pancha Pakshi" is limited to what is being found on [this](http://astrobix.com/horoscope/panchpakshi/) page.It is said that this knowledge was given to this world by the Tamil Siddhas.

My question-Which ancient Tamil text mentions about them and how valid an astrological system it is compared to Vedic astrology?

Also, i want to know in how much more detail(compared to the very minimal description found on the linked page) the laws(of Pancha Pakshi) are laid down in that Scripture.

On a personal note, i have found this Shastra to be quite interesting and useful too.

Comment: I've never heard of this before, but is the [_Surya Siddhanta_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surya_Siddhanta) related?

Comment: @CDR no that is different from Pancha Pakshi.